# Cannot access body in a HTTP post through NextJS

Tags: node.js, http, post, next.js

I think I'm missing something obvious, but I need another head to get me unstuck.

My objective: get access to the body of a POST request as shown in this page from nextjs.
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/building-forms

```
// root folder page.js file
//===========================

import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
 <main className={styles.main}>
    <div className={styles.description}>
        <p>
            <form action="/route" method="post">
                <label for="first">First name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="first" name="first"/><br/><br/>
                <label for="last">Last name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="last" name="last"/><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </p>
    </div>
</main>
  )
}
```

```
// /response/response.js
// ===========================
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
 
export async function GET(req, res) {
    console.log("====GET====");
    console.log(req.body);
    return NextResponse.json("get");
}

export async function POST(req) {
    const body = req.body;
    console.log(body);
  return NextResponse.json("post");
}
```

I fill out the form, and the browser routes correctly to the 'post' response, and the 'get' response lists when I submit.  However, on the server side, the response body is logged:

`ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }`

When I read the link, and all other documentation on nextjs and handling POST requests, the contents of the post as if it's an object, and not a readable stream.  Furthermore, I can't find anything on nextjs's website showing how to decode the readable stream, which seems a bit extensive of a solution for a common task.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing some mundane detail, like putting a decimal point in the wrong place, but I need help finding it.

Thanks a bunch peoples!

Chris Roode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are submitting your form as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can access your form data as follows:

```js
export async function POST(req) {
  const data = await req.formData();
  const firstName = data.get("first");
  const lastName = data.get("last");
  console.log({ firstName, lastName });
  return NextResponse.json("post");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! that got me in the right direction!

Comment: This is the only right way to handle POST request, im surprised they do not have it in the documentation

Comment: I believe you need to use `data.getAll` for fields that are arrays. `data.getAll` is also useful to keep the field type as array if there is only one entry in the array, otherwise `data.getAll` will turn it into a string.
There seems to also be another way to potentially get it working: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/46483#discussioncomment-7145802